# Architectural REST: How do I design a REST API for request+approval, 2 resources or 1?

Tags: rest

Let's say you are creating a REST API for a system that requires approval, e.g. a group membership system (closest analogy I can think of).

My resource for membership is `/membership`. I can see 3 possibilities:

**A. Single resource.**

So a new request is `POST /api/membership` which creates `{group: 10, user:1, status:"pending"}`. The org admin then approves by `PATCH /api/membership/:membership {status: "member"}`

Pro: single API. 
Con: Harder to easily differentiate between different member types; after all, a "pending" member isn't *really* a member. More importantly, a *request* to join isn't actually a *membership*.

**B. Separate resources.**

A new request is `POST /api/join` which creates a request to join `{group: 10, user: 1, status:"pending"}`. The org admin then approves by `PATCH /api/join/:join {status: "approved"}`. This then *automatically* (on the server) creates another resources at `/api/membership/:membership`.

Pro: Cleanly separates requests to join from actual memberships.
Con: Seems redundant (the properties of a request and a membership are similar), and depends on automatically juggling one resource from another on the back-end.

**C. Separate resources and requests.**

Just like Option B, except that the org admin approves in **2** steps. First `POST /api/membership {group:10, user:1}` and then `PATCH /api/join/:join {status:"approved"}`.

Pro: Cleanly separates requests from actual memberships. Also does not rely on background processing of one resource to affect another.
Con: Relying on the UI to do it is even messier!

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would handle this as two separate resources. A membership request and a membership are two different things. In addition, they may happen to have very similar properties now, but if they diverge in the future you'll be stuck. I would do

```
POST /membership-requests
{
   "memberId": 7,
   "groupId": 15
}
```

to create the request. The admin could do

```
GET /membership-requests?groupId=15&status=pending
```

to get requests by group, and then

```
PUT /membership-requests/12345
{
    "status": "approved"
}
```

to approve the request. You could use server-side business logic to detect the status change and create the membership. That PUT could then return a link to the membership:

```
{
    "memberId": 7,
    "groupId": 15,
    "status": "approved",
    "membership": "/memberships/298"
}
```

If you do this, your business logic needs to make sure that only pending requests can have their status changed.

If you only use one resource, how will you handle rejected memberships? To me, it doesn't make sense to do a

```
GET /memberships?status=rejected
```

because if the request is rejected, that's not really a membership.

Comment: Gee, great, I was leaning the other way, now I need to think the other. OK, @Eric, so how would I handle converting a pending request to an accepted request? I would need to both convert the status of the request from `pending` to `accepted` *and* create the `/membership` resource itself. Is that 2 requests (a PATCH and a POST) or 1 (PATCH to `/request`) which automatically creates the `/membership`, or perhaps the other ` (POST to `/membership`), which automatically updates the `/request`?

Comment: If you only want to do a single call, you can do a PUT /membership-requests which changes the status from "pending" to "approved". I edited my response to include that change. Otherwise, yes, it could be two calls, one to approve the request and another to create the membership. But the more I think about it, the more I like just the one PUT call with the membership creation happening on the server.

Comment: I am beginning to like this more and more. Much as we like to pretend REST eliminates the need for business-side logic, we know that isn't true. This would be a prime example. The only difference I see is that I would do a `PATCH` instead of `PUT`, but that is because I am a stickler for it.

Comment: @deitch I don't believe there's anything in the REST specs to suggest that no business-side logic should exist. If you are aware of something, though, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: no, there isn't. But one of the appeals of REST is that it simplifies the world into resources and verbs, and so eliminates unnecessary business logic. Some, however, is always necessary.

Comment: I finally got to completing tests (on 18hrs of flight), and then the implementation this week. Works really nicely. Had to do work around some odd things - e.g. when I `PATCH /api/memrequest/12345` the default should return the patched item, but I need to know what the new automatically created membership is, so I created an optional field on memrequest that includes the membership ID... which gives me a free audit trail. All in all, worked really nicely. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a complexity with it. Let's say I want to get my status with this group. Beforehand, I would do `GET /membership?group=123`. If I got back nothing, I was not in the group; if I got back an entry, I was a member; if I got back an entry with `{admin:true}`, I was a member and admin. All of this from one `GET`. Now, I need to know if I have a pending request also (if I am not already a member), so I need to also do `GET /membershiprequest?group=123`. Not as clean. Not the end of the world, but no single call will give me all membership status about this group.

Comment: @deitch You can modify your GET membership call to include information about requests also, if you want to.

Comment: how? A single `GET` that would get two separate resources?

Comment: @deitch No, modify the return values from GET /memberships to include pending memberships. Maybe when somebody creates a request, also create a memberhsip with pending status. Of course, then you're back to option A, having only one resource. The second call is not a big deal until you've profiled and it's a known bottleneck.

Comment: I see what you mean. No, I decided to go down this path to keep memberships and requests separate. That means I will need to make 2 requests, but as you said, not the end of the world.

Comment: this worked well for months, then became a more complex 3-level approval system. The question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819342/what-rest-resources-should-i-use-for-a-3-step-request-approval-system but the principle is request->tentative approval->approval. A tentative approval means, "Admin is saying s/he would like to approve, but wants to hold it in abeyance until all requests are seen."

Answer (score 4):

**Option A** is the one I'd choose. It's clean and simple to understand. If I was writing a client app to the API I'd be quickly able to grok it.

The other options force your resources to be verbs (`join`) which is usually a sign that you're on the wrong track. Well-designed RESTful APIs have the application protocol (usually HTTP) be the layer for your **verbs** (`POST`, `GET`, etc.) and the resources (represented by your URIs) be your **nouns**.

As to your Con for Option A:

> Con: Harder to easily differentiate between different member types;
>   after all, a "pending" member isn't really a member. More importantly,
>   a request to join isn't actually a membership.

I think this is a huge Pro, not a Con. For a resource representing members, "membership type" sounds like a perfectly reasonable attribute of that resource. There are plenty of states of membership that you could have later in the member's life, such as "good standing", "dunning", "elapsed", "revoked", "cancelled", "idle", or others. You wouldn't want to create a separate resource for each of those states either, so I'd stick with it being an attribute of the same `membership` resource to retain flexibility for the future.

Comment: I like your reasoning. I was starting to lean in that direction as well. I was thinking of "join" not as a verb as much as a noun, shorthand for a "join request". What it doesn't give you is good analytics, e.g. "how many join requests were there in the last 3 weeks, how many rejected, etc." Then again, I don't know that those analytics are a core part of the data model, as much as analytics you do on activity logs.

Comment: You could have analytics for the request/reject rate for sure. Each request or rejection would have resulted from a RESTful interaction with the membership resource, so just track that data as you see fit.