# How to model editing approved resources to create draft resources in a REST API

Tags: api, rest

The use case is handling a Configuration which needs to be reviewed and approved by users before it can be used.  The problem is modelling the edit case for an already approved Configuration.

As further background, versioning and keeping track of a history of drafts is out of scope, users would collectively approve a single outstanding draft.  An approved Configuration could be updated again with another pending draft so both approved and pending Configurations can be available side by side.

This is subtly different from  this question ([Architectural REST: How do I design a REST API for request+approval, 2 resources or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042944/architectural-rest-how-do-i-design-a-rest-api-for-requestapproval-2-resources)) as it doesn't cover updating an already approved resource.

One approach is to have a configuration resource with pending and approved sub-resources e.g.

```
/configurations/A/pending
/configurations/A/approved
```

(First /configurations/A/pending can be created, /configurations/A/pending can be patched such that /configurations/A/approved exists and /configurations/A/pending is removed.  It seems legal for  patch operation to have side effects on other resources(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2))

The question is then *how to handle the edit case* for an approved Configuration, which should create a pending configuration.

If we were to edit A, a PUT operation could be applied to /configurations/A/approved, but this seems strange as the result would be to create /configurations/A/pending.  But a PUT operation should be idempotent and have no side effects.

We could have a PUT operation on /configurations/A/pending but that also seems strange as logically we want to perform an operation on an approved resource.

Rather than having a singular Configuration with subresources, we could model separate pending and approved resources like so:

```
/configurations/pending/A
/configurations/approved/A

or we could go a step further and decouple the two and have different ids
/configurations/pending/123
/configurations/approved/A
```

But the same problem as listed above still remains.

Would like to hear other thoughts on how to model editing an approved resource.

Answer (score 0):

> But a PUT operation should be idempotent and have no side effects.

According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) PUT may have side effects as well, i.e. if you design a commit-like system similar to Git where a commit creates a new commit entry in the branch-tree while also moving the HEAD to the most recent version.

> As further background, versioning and keeping track of a history of drafts is out of scope, users would collectively approve a single outstanding draft. An approved Configuration could be updated again with another pending draft so both approved and pending Configurations can be available side by side.

If we would design this for the Web, we probably should have a page to list all configurations and drafts and have links for each entry to edit and remove such a configuration/draft. As only drafts can be accepted/rejected, depending whether the resource at hand is a draft or not may contain the possibility to accept/reject it.

As mentioned accepting a draft should lead to the removal of the draft and the creation/replacement of the actual configuration. There are actually a couple of ways you might achieve this, depending on how you design things. In general, a URI as a whole is, as its name suggest, a unique resource identifier. Segments within that URI do not necessarily state a parent-child relationship automatically. One might create a set of URIs though that map such an ancestor tree onto resources that a server treats as parents and children.

`PATCH` is basically an operation where a client should calculate a set of instructions the server should apply to transform the target resource from its current form to a desired form atomically. So, either all of the instructions succeed or none at all. Depending on the chosen representation type (Hint: negotiated media type) such an operation might be doable.

With  [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (`application/json-patch+json`) you need to target an ancestor resource that you address to *move* that resource to a different location. Such a payload may look like this:

```json
PATCH /configurations HTTP/1.1
Host: www.acme.com
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json; charset="utf-8"
ETag: 33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4
...

[
  { 
    "op": "move", 
    "from": "/drafts/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67", 
    "path": "/approved/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67" 
  }
]
```

This basically tasks the server to move the specified draft resource and move it to the approved configuration resources. I've just taken your suggested names here. In a REST architecture they don't really matter. As this request should be created by the client, ideally the server is already providing the client with all the data it needs to create such a request. On the Web HTML supports such a feature through the help of [Web forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) that defines the admissible syntax and semantics of each of the elements and attributes. For JSON [HAL-FORMS](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) and [Ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms) may be used to support you in this task.

In contrast to JSON Patch, [JSON Merge-Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386), that defines a set of default rules to apply on a document, however, won't allow you to move a document unless you apply custom logic on the server.

Moving a resource through patching may interfere with caching though as the request here is not directed towards the actual draft resource but an, in terms of the cache, unrelated one. As caches should [invalidate stored representations when an unsafe operation is performed on the target URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4), not using the same URI that was used for retrieving that resource state representation therefore won't invalidate a stored representation for that draft resource upon accepting or rejecting and thus may lead to stale response data upon requesting the current state.

While `PUT` may have side effects, these are more or less limited to creating new resources as a consequence of the document replacement. You might "bend your design" in a way to send an empty PUT request to the current draft that leads to the server copying the current content to the accepted configurations. As PUT is an unsafe operation performed on the same URI the representation state was requested from, caches should invalidate any stored representations for that URI. However, depending on your server design this may lead to unwanted "empty" drafts being still available. This operation, however, still fulfills the idempotent requirements. Upon resending a request the effective outcome should be the same on each request, an "empty" resource.

As `POST` is the general-purpose tool of HTTP, by processing a request according to the resource's own semantics, you can use it anyway you like. If you, however, use a different URI so send that request to you may end up with the same caching issues PATCH struggles.

[WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.9) specifies an idempotent, but not safe, `MOVE` operation, which can also be found in [IANAs HTTP method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml). This method does what its name suggests. If moves the target resource to the destination location by performing a copy step, followed by a consistency maintenance step which ends with a deletion step of the target resource. These three steps will be performed atomically as well. A request here just looks like this, assuming the same URIs from above.

```http
MOVE /configurations/drafs/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67
Host: www.acme.com
Destination: /configurations/approved/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67

...
```

As this operation is unsafe any cached representation will be invalidated automatically.

An other possibility is to not expose the state of the configuration within the URI mapping but keep it within the resource itself. This would also only operate on the same URI for that configuration itself. Internally you'd have to store the current active configuration as well as any draft version within the same resource. The downside here though is that you basically send plenty more data within a single response, i.e. the stored current version and all of the admissible draft version. You may introduce certain filters though to only retrieve accepted, rejected or pending configurations. The representation format such a payload is returned for should possibly support a client to easily identify the current and draft versions here.

> The question is then *how to handle the edit case* for an approved Configuration, which should create a pending configuration.

In case of JSON Patch you might try something like this:

```json
PATCH /configurations HTTP/1.1
Host: www.acme.com
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json; charset="utf-8"
ETag: 33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4
...

[
  { 
    "op": "copy", 
    "from": "/approved/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67", 
    "path": "/drafts/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67" 
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/drafts/eaff31bd-5291-4287-a7dd-fbe5b1e47b67/field1",
    "value": "new value"
  },
  ...
]
```

that first creates a copy of the current approved configuration version and then starts editing it. The atomic requirement of PATCH ensures that either all or none of the changes are applied.

In regards to updates of approved configurations via PUT, ideally the server issues a form-like representation to the client that teaches it how the resource state can be updated. Such representation would contain the necessary fields pre-filled with the current state that quickly allows a user to change the state of the resource. As editing an approved resource should resemble in the creation of a draft-resource first, the server should know about that and already instruct the client to send a `PUT` request to the draft endpoint rather than the original approved endpoint. Upon processing the response on the serve side it just needs to figure out whether there is content available or an empty payload to decide whether a draft was edited or accepted/rejected.

Via POST you are allowed to do whatever you want, so I don't think you need explanations in that case ...

On utilizing [WebDAV methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.8) you might need to split the instructions into multiple ones unfortunately. `COPY` will as its name implies copy the target resource to some location defined in the `Destination` header. Afterwards you can simply edit that file. If comparing it to a typical Web interaction, the resource could be copied already once a user clicks the edit button. The response to clicking the edit button will be a form representation containing the pre-filled data of the copied resource that upon clicking the submit button just performs a regular resource update on the draft resource. This interaction model needs to be mapped to a more generic layer though. Though the concepts remain the same. First a client needs to declare its interest in editing an already approved configuration, which leads to the creation of the copy in the draft space and afterwards returning a form representation allowing an application to supports its user to update the data.

In the last case, where you kept everything in one resource, creating a new draft on "editing" an accepted configuration only requires to add that modified version to the set of drafts. A server should compare the current configuration with the one provided in the request and if they differ, the provided payload needs to be added to the drafts.

As you can see, you have a couple of possibilities you can choose from. While patching seems to be a good choice, it doesn't coop with caching well and is also dependent on the media type negotiated. PUT demands a bit of "bending the rules" though could potentially be used to get the job done by also to invalidating any stored cache representation. POST is an all-purpose, general operation that can be used for literally anything you want or need. Last but not least redesigning your configurations and drafts into one single resource can also work.